# Chrome Cast Reviever App Terminates without cause

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am working on a app  that renders image in the the TV… A typical user will launch the  receiver app from a sender and shut the sender app.

Once the app is launched by the sender , the receiver loads a page that fetches and displays a set of images with text to a user.

The app works well except for the fact that it terminates randomly without cause after a certain period of time, as a result the user cannot see all the images the receiver app intends to display.

The receiver console logs are…

[1830.772s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"reason\":\"transport_too_long_inactive\",\"senderId\":\"10:client-94641\",\"type\":\"senderdisconnected\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender”}

[1830.781s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"reason":"transport_too_long_inactive","senderId":"10:client-94641","type":"sender disconnected”}

Also I used the HelloText Chrome app as the baseline for my app.

Any help would be highly appreciated…

Answer (score 0):

Well, the log says it is disconnected due to inactivity for too long. Is that the case when you see the disconnect?

Comment: Yes I did see that in the log, but what is inactivity… is it a) communication between the sender and the receiver, or is it b) the receiver being in an idle state

with regards to a) There is no communication between the sender and the receiver needed once the sender asked the receiver to run an app that shows images  and is done showing  images or running the app.

 with regards to b) the receiver is running the image rendering app, there is no more communication or activity needed between the sender and receiver as the receiver is not done finishing the task assigned. 

So what is inactivity

Comment: Are you sure your connectivity to sender is not broken due to network issues? There is a heartbeat between a sender and receiver that helps both sides realize that the other one is not accessible any longer. The error that you are seeing is pointing to failure to receive this heartbeat.

Comment: Thats what I suspected is the problem... in the case of chrome browsers... the user will launch the app and then engage with the app..he will step away from the PC... a typical computer with have a sleep on idle setup... so when the computer goes to sleep the network connectivity is lost... but the user is watching the app on his tv... so while a heart beat to a mobile device makes sense as it is always on... a pc on the other hand is not always on...

the question is... is there a work around...

Comment: I guess you should look at it differently: assume your sender gets disconnected, what is the right behavior for your receiver? In many cases when dealing with media centric apps, we want the receiver to continue playback. If that is the desired behavior, then let your receiver do nothing special. If the sender comes back to life, it has to reconnect to the same running session and then can take control of the situation. There is no need to force senders stay connected the whole time.

Comment: This exactly my point...but my use case if different... I have launched a slide show app on the receiver... the app is on slide 10 of 25... the sender chorme pc goes to sleep...now shouldn't the receiver finish all 25 slides... what the receiver does now is.. on slide 10(just an eg) it checks for a heart beat... but there is no sender as the pc is asleep

Comment: to answer you question by looking at things differently... if the sender is disconnected the receiver should inform the running app of such happening...the running app should instruct the receiver what to do...a) disconnect( immediate, or after time) or b) do nothing check back in X time, if the app does not handle these call backs from the receiver then the receiver should disconnect.

Comment: A receiver can register a callback to be notified when a sender connects or disconnects, so that is already in place. You are separating "running app" from "receiver", I am not sure what you mean, I imagine, in that context, by receiver you mean the SDK. Anyhow, when the cast receiver framework doesn't hear from a sender (heartbeat fails), it disconnects the sender and calls the listeners in the receiver application (if any) and then the receiver application can do as it sees appropriate. So is there some other functionality that is missing here that you expect the SDK/framework should do?

Comment: Ali... I really appreciate this exchange...

I understand that the  can register a callback to be notified when a sender connects or disconnects.... for now lets not worry about... "You are separating "running app" from "receiver" (I will get back to that)..." ...

Comment: I want start by to understanding a point you just made better....

You saying that if the cast receiver framework doesn't hear from a sender (heartbeat fails) it disconnects from sender and CAN call a listener in the receiver app...(how ?)... you further state..."the receiver application can do as it sees appropriate"  can it keep running and tell the cast receiver framework to not terminate..  (if yes how?) because if the receiver app can tell the cast receiver framework that its busy the cast receiver framework will not cause the inactivity time out...

Comment: For first question, the "cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected()" callback is the one that SDK uses to inform the receiver application that a sender was disconnected. Now for the second question, if your UI is active, framework doesn't kill your receiver app; I wrote an app that plays a slideshow and rotates when it reaches the end and I can let that run for hours without having *any* sender connected to that. If your UI doesn't change for a period of time, then framework stops your app to avoid any possible damage to your screen.

Comment: the app you wrote does it handle cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected() ? the app I have written is similar to yours but it shuts down  randomly and this is what appers in the log..."transport_too_long_inactive\"... I am observing the app its not stuck  and the UI is changing...

Comment: No, since it doesn't care about senders getting disconnected.

Comment: I think then the issue is that I have an app thats just like your as in it runs a slide show , but unlike your app my app stops and the error I get is as follows
1830.772s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"reason\":\"transport_too_long_inactive\",\"senderId\":\"10:client-94641\",\"type\":\"senderdisconnected\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender”}

Comment: Have you hooked into the onSenderDisconnected? If so, what do you do there?

Comment: oops...seems like the problem is here ... correct?
 castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected = function(event) {
            console.log('Received Sender Disconnected event: ' + event.data);
            if (window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length == 0) {
                window.close();
            }
        };

Comment: Yes, your implementation of that callback is responsible for the behavior you're seeing.